# Static html web page in maven with Docker

Tags: maven, docker

Hi I'm trying to copy my static html files from resources directory to docker build context, maven doesn't copy the files to the desired directory. here's my directory structure.

[image]

my pom file

```
  ...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/docker/build</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/frontend</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
COPY build/frontend /var/www/assets/
WORKDIR /var/www/assets/
EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pom.xml` will copy all files inside `/src/main/resources/frontend` to `build` folder of the docker build context but your `Dockerfile` is looking for `build/frontend`. Try to change to following such that it can copy correctly to the `build/frontend` :

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/docker/build</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>frontend/*.*</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
 </configuration>
```